# Results on convergence and runtime rates of proximal algorithms

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent, proximal-operators

Are there any known results on the convergence rates and computational runtime of proximal algorithms? I'm interested in finding out how well they scale with increasing number of input dimensions, but I'm having a difficult time finding any literature on this.